# Android provide additional content with In App Purchase

Tags: download, in-app-purchase

I have an Android app currently for sale on Google Play (current size 18mb) and I want to add an in app purchase that requires additional drawables (.png files) which will bring the size up to around 50mb.

Once the extra option is purchased it will enable/unlock a button to access the new feature. All other code will be in the APK from the original install.

Should I just load all the required drawables with the initial app (bloating it to 50mb from the start) or is there a way to load the extra drawables only when the in app feature has been purchased?

I'm worried that the larger size may be too big for existing users with older devices.

I have searched for some documentation on the subject but can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 0):

You could provide a web service from which users that have paid through whatever in app billing system you implement (Google Play, Amazon, Samsung App Store have their own billing services) can download the additional content.

Considerations.

1) A rooted phone could get access to the data you pre install therefore bypassing any in app billing however not many people will root their phone just to do this so maybe not a big deal.

2) You would need to set up a secure API on your web server protected with an SSL cert and HTTPS connections from your Android app.

I'd be interested to hear contributions on how others suggest you tackle this